# How do i draw a new rect on every click without removing the others?

Tags: python, pygame

im new to pygame and im trying to make the game draw a new rect on every mouse click (without removing the previous ones) and i just cant figure out how to do this...:\

I have made once a Tic-tac-toe game with pygame before and there i didnt have this problem, and seems like i did every thing almost similar...

So any help and/or explanation will be highly appreciated.

```
import pygame, sys, random
from settings import *
from buttonClass import *

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.running = True
        self.grid = testboard
        self.selected = None
        self.mousePos = None
        self.state = "playing"
        self.playingButtons = []
        self.endButtons = []
        self.loadButtons()

    def run(self):
        while self.running:
            if self.state == "playing":
                self.playing_events()
                self.playing_update()
                self.playing_draw()
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

#### PLAYING STATE ####

    def playing_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                selected = self.mouseOnGrid()
                if selected:
                    self.selected = selected
                else:
                    print("not on board")
                    self.selected = None

    def playing_update(self):
        self.mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    def playing_draw(self):
        self.window.fill(WHITE)
        if self.selected:
            self.drawSelection(self.window, self.selected)
            #pygame.display.update()
        self.drawGrid(self.window)
        pygame.display.update()


#### HELPER FUNCTIONS #####

    def drawSelection(self, window, pos):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, RED, ((pos[0]*cellSize)+gridPos[0], (pos[1]*cellSize)+gridPos[1], cellSize, cellSize))

    def drawGrid(self, window):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, BLACK, (gridPos[0], gridPos[1], WIDTH-150, HEIGHT-150), 2)
        for x in range(5):
            pygame.draw.line(window, BLACK, (gridPos[0] + (x * cellSize), gridPos[1]), (gridPos[0] + (x * cellSize), gridPos[1] + 450))
            pygame.draw.line(window, BLACK, (gridPos[0], gridPos[1]+ (x * cellSize)), (gridPos[0] + 450, gridPos[1] + (x * cellSize)))

    def mouseOnGrid(self):
        if self.mousePos[0] < gridPos[0] or self.mousePos[1] < gridPos[1]:
            return False
        if self.mousePos[0] > gridPos[0] + gridSize or self.mousePos[1] > gridPos[1] + gridSize:
            return False
        return ((self.mousePos[0]-gridPos[0])//cellSize, (self.mousePos[1]-gridPos[1])//cellSize)

    def loadButtons(self):
        pass
```

heres the settings.py file if u want to test it.

```
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 600

# Colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)

# boards
testboard = [
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""],
        ["", "", "", "", ""]
    ]

# posiotons and sizes
gridPos = (75,100)
cellSize = 90
gridSize = cellSize*5
```

Comment: standard rule: if you have many elements then keep them on list. So you should keep all selected rectangles on list and use `for`-loop to draw all rectangles. `self.selected = []` , `self.selected.append(selected)`, `for item in self.selected: self.drawSelection(self.window, item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In playing_draw, when you fill the window with white, you are removing all previous rectangles. Then, you only draw the rectangle you have most recently selected.

To draw all rectangles that you have selected before, you will need to keep track of all of them.

Initialize self.selected to a set. A list would suffice as well but might end up with duplicates in them.

```
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.running = True
        self.grid = testboard
        self.selected = set()
        self.mousePos = None
        self.state = "playing"
        self.playingButtons = []
        self.endButtons = []
        self.loadButtons()
```

Then whenever a click is detected, add the selection to self.selected

```
    def playing_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                selected = self.mouseOnGrid()
                if selected:
                    self.selected.add(selected)
                else:
                    print("not on board")
                    self.selected = None
```

Finally, use a loop to draw all selected rectangles in playing_draw.

```
    def playing_draw(self):
        self.window.fill(WHITE)
        for selected in self.selected:
            self.drawSelection(self.window, selected)
        self.drawGrid(self.window)
        pygame.display.update()
```